# ESP32 restarting when relay is turned on

Tags: power-supply, noise, esp32, spike

I am designing a PCB with a 5V relay that controls an external DIN mounted latching relay (red line with the "1."):

[image: Wiring]

The problem I have, is that the ESP32 often restarts after turning the latching relay on/off.
This only happens if the latching relay is connected. I don't have any problems when the 5V relay triggers without being connected to anything.

When I connect the oscilloscope to the 3.3V rail, I can see a spikes from **-40V to 50V (Vpp ~ 90V)**

[image: img]
[image: img]

This is my schematic for the Power Supply and relays:

[image: img]

RAC PS datasheet: [datasheet](https://recom-power.com/pdf/Powerline_AC-DC/RAC05-K.pdf) 
Relay PCN-105D: [datasheet](https://www.mouser.ch/datasheet/2/418/5/ENG_DS_PCN_series_relay_data_sheet_E_0820-1265050.pdf) 
Project full schematic, layout, etc: [github](https://github.com/crgarcia12/electronics-homeassistant-lightscontroll%5Dhttps://github.com/crgarcia12/electronics-homeassistant-lightscontroll)

Can those spikes be the responsible of the ESP32 restarting? 
What can I do to fix that?

Thanks!

[Edit]
My probe is connected to the thermal pad of the TO220, and to a pin header where I expose the GND:

[image: probes]

And this is my entire setup 
[image: setup]

Comment: Yup those spikes are most probably reseting your controller! I have seen similar situations. The most simplest and easy solution I see is use an isolator. Since its a relay I think a photocoupler should do the trick. EL817C is cheap and easy to use.

Comment: Already tried a flyback diode at the relays?

Comment: @Bubu where would you add the isolator? I think the spikes are coming from the mains. I control the relays using a uln2003a driver

Comment: @CarlosGarcia On your microcontroller's digital output pins that signal your ULN to switch realys

Comment: @RemyHx I am using ULN2003A, that has flyback diodes. I anyways think the problem comes from the mains line, because when I unplug the latching relay and leave the PCB relays in the air, the ESP does not reset

Comment: IF the spikes are coming form your mains, your power supply isn't good enough at decoupling / ripple rejection to power your microncontroller power rails.

Comment: To verify/debug IF it is your power spike are caused due to mains OR lack of isolation, use a battrey to power your digital circuit. If the spikes go away with battrey then your power supply circuit need imporvment. Else if it doesn't help then definetley your digital system needs isolation

Comment: @Bubu I will try that out now. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: THANK YOU for including schematics! Problem seems strange though, I have no idea why connecting the latching relay to this would cause it to do that. When you test it with the latching relay, there is no load on the latching relay (no lightbulb)?

Comment: Thank you @user253751. Yes there is, I connected a light bulb to it. I will take a picture on the setup tomorrow. Maybe this has something to do with my scope. I did a quick test, and I can see noise even if I turn on the latching relay from another manual switch - I need to test a bit more to confirm it

Comment: When you attach the scope how do you attach the ground?

Comment: @user253751.. I will post a picture in few minutes. That could easily be an issue, I am a self-thought on electronics, I usually do very wrong even the most basic things :)

Comment: What happens if you add more decoupling capacitors in parallel to the existing ones?

Comment: thanks @winny! I added some more (using a jumper wire) and still fails, I also added a flyback diode and same behaviour. I will try to see if this is just a scope problem, and there is a "ground loop" (whatever that means :) )

Comment: No jumper wires, decoupling capacitors as close to and straight across ICs. If you have access to an oscilloscope you can measure if this is a problem.

Comment: @winny, can I solder capacitors on top of capacitors? Currently the ESP has 2 different ones, but I don't have too much space to put new ones (layout: https://ibb.co/xYWmZMX)

Comment: 22 uF should be sufficient but it’s my go-to first try when something is resetting. Yes, solder on top of it. Other possibilities: is your ground garbage by any chance? Can anything pull reset pin?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the reset reason of the ESP32 through `esp_reset_reason()`

If it's "brownout detector" you know the spikes are the cause and you need better isolation. You could turn-off brownout detection if you want (I do after I discovered that starting a radio when my device was USB powered was doing that), but strongly discouraged because BP is there for a reason.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I checked the reset reason and it is `Power On Reset`. I have no clue what it means. Will try with disabling that, to at least be sure that that is the problem

Answer (score 1):

I think it is unlikely that you are actually getting those high voltage transients on the 3.3 V logic rail, or you would be seeing damage to those components. More likely the transients form the AC relay coil are being coupled to the scope probe via inductive or magnetic coupling, or through a ground loop. Try connecting the scope probe to the ground point, and you will probably still see significant noise.

Are you seeing this mostly when the relay opens?

Adding a snubber across the AC coil of the relay will probably help. Try something like a 100 ohm resistor in series with a 220 nF film capacitor across the coil to see if it helps.

You could also try adding more capacitors across the 3.3V logic supply, as well as a TVS diode to absorb such transients.

Comment: Yes! I see this mostly when the relay opens. Since the outer it is a latching relay, I turn on the PCB relay and turn it off 200ms later, so I keep it on for a very short amount of time. I am not sure what you mean with `Try connecting the scope probe to the ground point`. Do you mean both connector from the probe connected to the PCB GND?

Comment: Yes. If you still see this noise, it is being picked up by the probe or through a ground loop. If the shorted input shows no noise, you have serious problems on the 3.3V power supply.

Comment: @CarlosGarcia Correct probing is vital! See here: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Edel3eduRj4