# Best PCB relays for inductive loads

Tags: relay, solid-state-relay, esp32, inductive, latching-relay

**The questions:**

1. What should I look for when searching for a PCB relay to drive inductive loads?
2. Any tips on how I could find relays like that (digikey, etc do not allow you to filter by snubber, peak-switching, etc)

**The context:**
I am driving DIN mounted latching relays with a custom build PCB.
I usually switch on and off the PCB relays very quickly, around 100ms.

[image: System diagram]
[image: img]

So far, I have been using [PCN105D (datasheet)](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Data%20Sheet%7FPCNH_Relay%7F0519%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_DS_PCNH_Relay_0519.pdf%7F3-1461491-0)

The problem I have is that this relays creates very large spikes, that I tried to fix with capacitors and diodes on top of the relay driver ([ULN2003A datasheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ULN200xA.pdf)) but nothing seems to work. ([link to another question describing the issue](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/629875/esp32-restarting-when-relay-is-turned-on/629912?noredirect=1#comment1667582_629912))

I have tried replacing the relay with an SSR and that seems to fix my problems.
Reading as much as I could find, To drive inductive loads from my PCB, I need a peak-switching SSR relay with an internal RI Snubber.

The problem I have is that I could not find small&slim (under 25x5mm) PCB relay with internal snubber, and even less with peak-switching.

**The questions again :)**

1. What should I look for when searching for a PCB relay to drive inductive loads?
2. Any tips on how I could find relays like that (digikey, etc do not allow you to filter by snubber, peak-switching, etc)

Full schematics: [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/crgarcia12/electronics-homeassistant-lightscontroll/main/PCB/schematics-v19-jlcpcb/readme-media/board-schematics.svg)
Full PCB layour: [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/crgarcia12/electronics-homeassistant-lightscontroll/main/PCB/schematics-v19-jlcpcb/readme-media/board-pcb.png)
Full project: [link](https://github.com/crgarcia12/electronics-homeassistant-lightscontroll)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138522/discussion-on-question-by-carlos-garcia-best-pcb-relays-for-inductive-loads).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a series resistor-capacitor (RC snubber) between the lines that control your latching relay. They can go on the board, next to the relay, or be built/spliced into the cable somewhere along the way.

The capacitor should be 220VAC rated and non-polarized, 10nF-100nF probably. The resistance should be on the lower end, 1-10Ohms maybe. The resistor wattage will vary depending on the size of the capacitor and it's resistance. You're not switching frequently so I imagine 1W should be okay.

Comment: Thank you! I found a relay with a snubber on it. I will try that out! Here is the datasheet: https://www3.panasonic.biz/ac/e_download/control/relay/solid-state/catalog/semi_eng_aqg.pdf